# Difference between map and Flow

Tags: java, akka

From reading a Google groups post from 2016 : “.map() is converted to a .via()”

src : https://groups.google.com/g/akka-user/c/EzHygZpcCHg

Are the following lines of code equivalent :

```
Source.repeat(json).take(3).via(mapToDtoFlow).to(printSink).run(actorSystem);
Source.repeat(json).take(3).map(x -> mapper.readValue(x, RequestDto.class)).to(printSink).run(actorSystem);
```

Are there scenarios when a map should be used instead of flow?

src :

RequestDTO :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.extern.jackson.Jacksonized;

import java.util.Date;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@Jacksonized
public class RequestDto {
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sss")
    private final Date datePurchased;
}
```

StreamManager (contains main method) :

```
import akka.Done;
import akka.NotUsed;
import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.typed.javadsl.Behaviors;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Flow;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Sink;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Source;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

public class StreamManager {

    final static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private static final Flow<String, RequestDto, NotUsed> mapToDtoFlow = Flow.of(String.class)
            .map(input -> mapper.readValue(input, RequestDto.class))
            .log("error");

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        final ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create(Behaviors.empty(), "actorSystem");
        final Sink<RequestDto, CompletionStage<Done>> printSink = Sink.foreach(System.out::println);

        final String json = "{\"datePurchased\":\"2022-03-03 21:32:017\"}";

        Source.repeat(json).take(3).via(mapToDtoFlow).to(printSink).run(actorSystem);
        Source.repeat(json).take(3).map(x -> mapper.readValue(x, RequestDto.class)).to(printSink).run(actorSystem);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is converted to a `via`, but it's not an exactly syntactically equivalent `via` as you'd get from `Flow.of().map()`.

The first would translate to a `.via(Map(f))`, where `Map` is a [`GraphStage` which implements the map operation](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/9c5281bff88004f8772f74ecae156fddcdc8196d/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/impl/fusing/Ops.scala#L38).

In the second case, the `mapToDtoFlow` (ignoring the `log`) would itself be (in Scala notation) `Flow[String].via(Map(f))` so you'd be adding another layer of `via`: `.via(Flow[String].via(Map(f)))`.

For all intents and purposes, they're the same (I suspect that the materializer, when it comes time to interpret the `RunnableGraph` you've built, will treat them identically).

Taking the `.log` into account, `mapToDtoFlow` is equivalent (again in Scala):

```scala
Flow[String]
  .via(Map(f))
  .via(Log(...))
```

There are basically three levels of defining streams in Akka Streams, from highest level to lowest level:

- the Java/Scala DSLs
- the Java/Scala Graph DSLs
- `GraphStage`s

The DSLs merely specify succinct ways of building `GraphStage`s and the fundamental way to link `GraphStage`s with `Flow` shape is through the `via` operation.